# How to build a library from solution file in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, static-libraries

I am somewhat frustrated because what I am asking seems to be common knowledge and isnt explained in any tutorials:

When I download some kind of library/framework (for example assimp), and create a "solution" file with cmake. So far everything is fine. But now I have got a solution file but I want to have a .lib file, right? How can I get it? When I open the solution with VS and click "Build", there is some processing, but after the processing and some console messages, nothing really changed. Is there some kind of way to tell VS: "I want a lib file from this in C:/myDirectory"?

Would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the project properties where the exact output directory for each configuration is.

You can look it up here:

[image]

Comment: Just so I have it right: SolutionRoot is the folder where the solution file is located, right? For some reason there is nor a bin neither a debug or release folder in there after building the solution in VS...

Comment: The exact location of this folder varies for different languages. In c++ there should be a folder for each project in the SolutionRoot (where the .sln file is). You open the project folder you want the lib files from and in that project there should be a folder named after the configuration you choosed to build the project. In that folder there are finally the lib files

Comment: Well, I found that output directory field, and set it to a new folder, but it didnt appear after building. Theres definitely something wrong with either my VS or myself I guess.